# How to retrive Bigquery billing details from GCP console or UI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

My team is using bigquery for our product development. Other bill of Rs 5159 got generated for one days transaction.

I checked the transaction details and

BigQuery Analysis: 15.912 Tebibytes [Currency conversion: USD to INR using rate 69.155]

Is is possible to somehow find out more details about the transactions like table name, queries that were executed and exact time of execution?

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery automatically sends audit logs to [Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/#stackdriver-logging-exports) and provide the ability to do aggregated analysis on logs data. You can see [BigQuery schema for exported logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/bigquery) for details

As quick example: Query cost breakdown by identity
This query shows estimated query costs by user identity. It estimates costs based on the list price for on-demand queries in the US. This pricing may not be accurate for other locations or for customers leveraging flat-rate billing.

```
  #standardSQL
  WITH data as
  (
    SELECT
      protopayload_auditlog.authenticationInfo.principalEmail as principalEmail,
      protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent AS jobCompletedEvent
    FROM
      `MYPROJECTID.MYDATASETID.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_YYYYMMDD`
  )
  SELECT
    principalEmail,
    FORMAT('%9.2f',5.0 * (SUM(jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics.totalBilledBytes)/POWER(2, 40))) AS Estimated_USD_Cost
  FROM
    data
  WHERE
    jobCompletedEvent.eventName = 'query_job_completed'
  GROUP BY principalEmail
  ORDER BY Estimated_USD_Cost DESC
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `MYPROJECTID.MYDATASETID.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_YYYYMMDD was not found in location US`. I mean, I did the apropriate substitutions in MYPROJECTID, MYDATASETID and YYYYMMDD, of course . How to know the location of my project?

Answer (score 2):

As of last year BigQuery provides `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables that also give access to job information via `JOBS_BY_*` views. The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT` views even include **the exact query** alongside the processed bytes. It might not be 100% accuracte (because bytes processed != bytes billed) but it should allow you to gain a good overview over your costs, which queries triggered them an who the initiator was.

**Example**

```sql
SELECT 
  creation_time,
  job_id,
  project_id,
  user_email,
  total_bytes_processed,
  query
FROM
  `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER
```

The most "efficient" way to keep an eye on the cost is using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION` view as it automatically includes all projects of the organization. You need to be Organization Owner or Organization Administrator to use that view, though.

From there you can figure out which jobs were the most expensive (= get their job id) and form there drill down via `JOBS_BY_PROJECT` to get the exact query.

See https://www.pascallandau.com/bigquery-snippets/monitor-query-costs/ for a more comprehensive explanation.

Comment: this also shows queries made via local python client?

Comment: What do you mean with "local python client"? Since you must use credentials (and thus a billing project) i presume that every query shows up.

Comment: I did several queries in my local machine using this:https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html . However, these queries don't appear in the table create by the query that you showed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Export Billing Data to BigQuery

Tools for monitoring, analyzing and optimizing cost have become an important part of managing development. Billing export to BigQuery enables you to export your daily usage and cost estimates automatically throughout the day to

1. export data to a CSV,JSON file

However, if you use regular file export, you should be aware that regular file export captures a smaller dataset than export to BigQuery. For more information about regular file export and the data it captures, see Export Billing Data to a File.

[image]

2. to a BigQuery dataset you specify.

After you enable BigQuery export, it might take a few hours to start seeing your data. Billing data automatically exports your data to BigQuery in regular intervals, but the frequency of updates in BigQuery varies depending on the services you're using. Note that BigQuery loads are ACID compliant, so if you query the BigQuery billing export dataset while data is being loaded into it, you will not encounter partially loaded data.

Follow the step by step guide: How to enable billing export to BigQuery
https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery